# android.widget.ImageView scaling produces ugly results

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, scaling

I'm trying to scale an image in an ImageView on Android, but no matter what settings I try, the scaled-down image always looks ugly. Here is an image produced by my code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/agDA4.png

The image on the left is pre-scaled using ImageMagick on my desktop computer. ImageView has no problem showing this image. The image on the right is the one that is actually scaled by the ImageView, and as you can clearly see, it looks quite ugly :/

The code that produces both of the above images is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout body = new RelativeLayout(this);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        ImageView iv;

        iv = new ImageView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(34, 34);
        params.leftMargin = i*50;
        body.addView(iv, params);

        AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

        try
        {
            BufferedInputStream buf;
            if(i == 0)
                buf = new BufferedInputStream(am.open("images/search_34x34.png"));
            else
                buf = new BufferedInputStream(am.open("images/search.png"));

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
            BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            bd.setAntiAlias(true);
            iv.setImageDrawable(bd);
            buf.close();
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException e)
        {
        }
    }

    setContentView(body);
}
```

Please tell me if I am missing something. I just cannot believe that Android scales images this badly (actually, I find it hard to believe that this is the default behavior).

Also note that I do NOT want to pre-scale the images, as my app has to deal with images from unknown origin, so I have to scale on the fly.

Comment: try to enable bitmap filtering `bd.setFilterBitmap(true)`

Comment: I forgot to mention that the source image is actually much larger (294x294) and looks very crisp, so the ugliness does not stem from a badly chosen source image.

Comment: @vmironov: thanks, I just tried it, but unfortunately no effect :/

Comment: Here is the original image: http://i.imgur.com/gUc1I.png Note that the image is white on a transparent background (don't open it on a white background, or you will not see anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You have to set the scaleType inside Your xml Layout. For example

```
     <ImageView
          android:scaleType="center"
       </ImageView>
```

There are following scaleTypes:

1. CENTER
2. CENTER_CROP
3. CENTER_INSIDE
4. FIT_CENTER
5. FIT_END
6. FIT_START
7. FIT_XY
8. MATRIX

You could see about here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

### EDIT

Tried some stuff and now I get the same result even with other pics. I recognized, that when I am scaling down an image inside a mobile phone, all looks good. I used for example an imageView with 120x120 dp and a resource with 300x300px. If I use the same imageView on an tablet, even 120x120, and the same resource image with the same size, it looks very bad. I think the only way to get rid of this is to scale the image outside your app to the needed sizes before setting it to Your project. For Example, if You use an imageView with 200x200dp, scale the image near to this size. If You support multiple screen sizes, and you set the sizes of this imageView for a tablet to 500x500dp, scale Your image near to this size. Sure, this only will work good, if You got an Image that has a higher resolution than the biggest imageView.
I Know this no satisfying answer, but this is the only way I see for this problem.

Comment: Actually I had the scale type FIT_XY set on my ImageView. But I removed it from the code above to simplify the code. The setting has no effect regarding the quality of the scaling.

Comment: what happens if you set  bd.setAntiAlias(false); instead of (true)?

Comment: thats strange, can´t see any error for now. I am trying some stuff at this weekend. If You get no solution until then, and I found out why, I will give You an example

Comment: I´ve tried some things, but can´t get this result. could You give me the original files from this picture?

Comment: Here is the original image: i.imgur.com/gUc1I.png Note that the image is white on a transparent background (don't open it on a white background, or you will not see anything :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are scaling down your bitmap. I think you are trying to jam the high resolution bitmap in to a ImageView with smaller dimensions.

[Here is a document on scaling the bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). The technique described works well with scaling the bitmaps on the fly also.

Comment: Well, the effect of this "jamming" the bitmap into a too-small image view is that it gets scaled, albeit with bad quality. I already tried scaling bitmaps directly (similarly to the technique described in the page you linked to). Since that didn't work well (similar quality problems), I actually turned from scaling the bitmap directly to scaling using an imageview. Anyway, I will try the techniques you mentioned. Perhaps that description contains some parameter I missed before.

Comment: It is true that ImageView widget handles scaling for you, but it might not be appropriate all the time. Moreover the scaling is dependent on the dimensions of the view itself (As in absolute dimensions in dp or relative dimensions to fit parent or wrap content). From my experience scaleType of FitXy does not maintain the aspect ratio, which tends to distort the image.[Check this post](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846580&seqNum=2) and experiment with different scale types.